# Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading, javafx

When I use javaFx Application longer time then I got exception as follow and my application is going very slow.

**Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:2694)
    at java.lang.String.(String.java:203)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.toString(StringBuilder.java:405)\
    ...**

**VM arguments are:**

-XstartOnFirstThread

-XX:MaxPermSize=256m

-Xms128m

-Xmx512m

How to solve this exception?

Thanks.

Comment: Increase your heap to 1G -Xmx1G (or even more based on what the application does and provided you have that much capacity in the box where application runs). Even if it doesnt work you would need to profile your application.

Comment: I tried this not not working.

Comment: try profiling your app. Also if you dont mind can you brief what your app does (paste everything in the question)? and where do you think most of the memory is eaten up? Are there any leaks and so on?

Comment: can you post ur code?

Answer (score 2):

Java applications are allowed to use a limited amount of memory. This limit is specified during application startup. To make things more complex, Java memory is separated into two different regions. These regions are called heap space and permgen.

The size of those regions is set during the Java Virtual Machine (JVM) launch by specifying parameters such as *-Xmx* and *-XX:MaxPermSize*. In your case you have allowed the heap size to grow up to 512m via specifying the -Xmx parameter.

So – the “java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space” error will be triggered when you try to add more data into the heap space area, but there is not enough room for it.

The first solution is easy and obvious - when you have ran out of a particular resource, you should increase the availability of such a resource. In your case: when your application does not have enough Java heap space memory to run properly, fixing it is as easy as increasing heap space in your JVM launch configuration, for example to 1GB as following:

```
-Xmx1024m
```